# What is the meaning of "big boys"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Can I use the term "Big boys" to describe large companies like Google and Facebook? Can I use it to mention managers and employers?

Is it a general sentence that describe high position in any field?

And How to know who is the referred to in some context?

Comment: "Big boys" is informal, and a somewhat playful turn of phrase when used in business contexts. A five-year-old boy calls the boys who are eight-years-old "big boys".  Used by analogy, it refers to entities with a larger market presence and greater "muscle" (economies of scale, etc)

Comment: @TRomano Answer! Please! There's no reason not to and this will help everyone out if you do. We need to get out of the habit (I do it too) of answering in comments.

Comment: Okeydoke, but I don't have the will to document it. :)

Comment: @Cat - I agree with TRomano, and with you. On one hand, there's nothing wrong with a "starter" comment to give the O.P. some immediate help. (I often do this in hopes that someone will come along and leave a more well-documented answer.) I agree with you, too, that we don't want that initial comment to be the end of the discussion, but I think it's okay to leave the answering to someone else - particularly when the commenters don't have the time to leave as detailed an answer as they'd like.

Comment: Answering in comments is acceptable when the answer is little more than a comment. Good answers cite reputable, outside sources of information to back up their claims, provide illustrative examples (or links to them), and are generally more substantive. The habit we (including me!) need to get into is satisfying these criteria.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Big boys" is informal, and a somewhat playful turn of phrase when used in business contexts. A five-year-old boy calls the boys who are eight-years-old "big boys". Used by analogy, it refers to entities with a larger market presence and greater "muscle" (economies of scale, etc)

Comment: The bitches would disagree.

Comment: It also can be somewhat pejorative. By describing people as "big boys" you can also mean that they are not mature. Without the benefit of inflection or context, if a male writer said "the big boys" I would assume it was jokingly positive and if a female writer said it I would assume it was jokingly negative. Fortunately it is rarely the case that we don't have enough context to make that distinction.

Comment: @AlfredBr: Oh for goodness's sake... seriously?